# Incorrect values with auto iterator on std::list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, iterator, auto

I firstly intialize a hotel object and then initialize some room objects and print their id's respectively (which print out correctly.)

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
    Room r(1, 30);
    hotel.addRoom(r);
    cout << "Id: " << r.getId() << endl;
}
```

Then, I do this iteration on the list:

```
cout << "Initialized rooms with Ids: ";
for(auto iterator : hotel.getRooms()){
    cout << iterator->getId() << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Also, here is the implementation on those methods, on the Hotel class:

```
//header
list<Room*> rooms;

//source
list<Room*> & Hotel::getRooms(){
    return rooms;
}
```

And look at the output!
[image: Output]

Every other part (like id generation and construction of objects) is tested and works fine.

Comment: I will assume addRoom works as expected. In that case you have std::list of dangling pointers.

Comment: I guess the problem is somewhere in your Room class. Please supply that code, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted a definition for the `addRoom` function, by the power of deduction I conclude it does something similar to:

```
void Hotel::addRoom(const Room& room) {
    rooms.push_back(&room);
}
```

And then given the following loop:

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
{
    // This creates a Room object local to each iterator of the loop
    Room r(1, 30);
    // This adds the address of this local variable in the list
    hotel.addRoom(r);
    cout << "Id: " << r.getId() << endl;
    // The variable r is destroyed here
}
```

So in the end your `std::list<Room*>` is filled with dangling pointers - pointers which point to memory which is no longer yours. This causes undefined behavior.

I recommend you drop the pointers altogether and change to:

```
class Hotel 
{
    std::list<Room> rooms;

public:
    void addRoom(const Room& room) {
        rooms.push_back(room);
    }
    std::list<Room>& Hotel::getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }
    const std::list<Room>& Hotel::getRooms() const {
        return rooms;
    }
};
```

Comment: I realise what you're saying, since there's a lot of code already using pointers like this, i'll switch necessary parts to use new .